# Call the method on another component with a router

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I have a button on a table, and when I click it, I want to go to another component and open a specific element, I mean, navigate to this other component and call a method (GetReport).

How may I achieve this with Router or something like that?

I'm using angular 6 with TypeScript

Comment: Do you want to call this method every time the target component opens?

Comment: What did you do so far, provide a minimal viable example where you stuck. Better use https://stackblitz.com/. Other wise your question is unsalvageable...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is usually not done by calling a method on another component from the router, but rather providing the information to be used from the component triggering the navigation and retrieving it on the landing component by injecting the router.

Two possible solutions using the router are:

1. Include the information you want available as part of the route and retrieve it using `ActivatedRoute` on the landing component as described [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#route-parameters).
2. Use `query parameters` as described [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#query-parameters-and-fragments) to make information available when navigating to other routes and retrieve it using `ActivatedRoute` on the landing component

Another way of doing this is by centrally storing data on your application and subscribing for changes on the components on which data is needed. Two possible ways for achieving this are:

3. Create a service which has an Rxjs Subject and a method for setting the next value, and subscribe to changes on the subject on the landing component
4. Use a state management solution (like NGRX or NGXS), dispatch an action for setting the selected element and select information from the store inside landing component

As per the information you provided, it seems that the best approach for your use case would be 1) or 2), depending if the information should be part of the route or a query parameter.